# nginx config redirect file-url to folder-url (/abc.html => /abc/)

Tags: nginx, redirect, url-rewriting, config

I am trying to rewirte the old url
`https://www.example.com/en/portfolio/my-portfolio.html`
to  `https://www.example.com/en/portfolio/my-portfolio/`

```
location /en/portfolio/ {
    rewrite ^(.*)(.html)$ https://www.example.com/en/portfolio/$1/ permanent;
  }
```

This gives me a 404.
I need `https://www.example.com`. This is pointing to a CDN, while `https://www2.example.com` is the nginx server. `https://www.example.com/en/portfolio/index.html` has not to be rewriten.

`https://www.example.com/en/portfolio/index.html` => no redirect
`https://www.example.com/en/portfolio/` => no redirect
`https://www.example.com/en/portfolio/anything-else.html` => `https://www.example.com/en/portfolio/anything-else/`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This regex works finding everthink before .html, but not match if group contains "index":

```
location /en/portfolio/ {
   rewrite ^(.*)(?<!index).html$ https://www.example.com$1/ permanent;
}
```